# Vite Dev Servers HMR not working with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, webpack, webpack-dev-server, vite

I'm trying to migrate our application from webpack to vite. The backend is an spring boot MPA, some pages using vue. I've set up the build step, which is working fine! However, its not possible to use HMR with the vite dev server. If changing an asset (css, js, img, ...), those changes are not applied. I need to make a full build again...

Webpacks HMR just works out of the box if I applied this to my webpack.config:

```
devServer: {
    proxy: {
      "/": "http://localhost:8080",
    },
    port: 8081,
  },
```

Vite (dev mode with debug flag) seems like to recognize the changes but cannot resolve the modules?

```
  vite:hmr [file change] src/main/css/main.css +0ms
  vite:hmr [no modules matched] src/main/css/main.css +1ms
```

Could you please tell  me what I'm doing wrong? I've set up an example repo, which u can use to reporduce the problem. Just have a look at the README.
https://github.com/Theiaz/spring-boot-mpa-with-vite

Thanks for your help!

Edit: **As a comparison i also setup the same project with webpack**, which is working with HMR: https://github.com/Theiaz/spring-boot-with-webpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution by following the [backend integration guide](https://vitejs.dev/guide/backend-integration.html).

There are some differences between webpacks HMR and vites. Have a look at the  [github repository](https://github.com/Theiaz/spring-boot-mpa-with-vite) for a working solution.

Comment: Hi! I have no problem with HMR in Vite with "my" Spring Boot setup, it works out of the box. Maybe due to changes in newer versions of Vite?! But I have problems e.g. when I do a browser reload or configuring the dev server proxy in a more generic/dynamic way. I've just created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76309242/switching-from-vue-cli-to-vite-with-spring-boot-as-backend-dev-server-not-worki - maybe you have an idea. :-)

Comment: Can you update the answer to specify what was wrong and what was the solution?