# Switching from Vue CLI to Vite with Spring-Boot as backend, dev server not working as expected

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vue.js, vite, vue-cli

There are several ways to integrate a Vue project into a Spring Boot project.

Using webpack based build tools (e.g. vue-cli) I've successfully done it several times in the following way:

- configure the `outputDir` of the build process such that its output is placed in e.g. `/static/dist/` (finally) **inside the Java class path** of the Spring Boot project. This way these static assets can be served via the URL `/dist/...`. To have the correct URLs in the generated `index.html`  the `publicPath` must of course be set to `/dist/`.
- configure Vue Router using HTML5 mode (history mode) with some `baseUrl` not equal to `/` (was necessary in a large productive system) *and not equal to* `/dist/` - let's say its `baseUrl` is equal to `/vue/`. Now, in Spring Boot, forward all requests matching `/vue/**` to `/dist/index.html` such that the Vue Router can take over handling the given URL.

This way I had no problems in production. And there was no difference in behaviour using the provided dev server in development mode - live reload (HMR) works as expected and also talking to the Spring Boot backend was unproblematic (of course a proxy must be configured for the dev server).

Using this setup (different `baseUrl`s for the build process and for the Vue Router) with Vite **seems to be perfectly fine in production mode!** (at least I've had no problems up to now)

But in development mode I experience several problems with the built in dev server. Probably due to the different `baseUrl`s I get, for example, the following message if I do a browser reload:

> The server is configured with a public base URL of /dist/ - did you mean to visit /dist/vue/ instead?

Moreover I have problems to configure the proxy of the dev server. Specific URLs can be proxied quite simple but I don't know how to configure the proxy in a more generic way like I do it in webpack based builds (without destroying the live reload which initially works well in Vite).

All in all it's quite complex and difficult to explain. For this reason I created a **very simple** demo project in this [github repository](https://github.com/drahkrub/demo-spring-vite-vue3).

Comments, help and PRs are welcome! ;-)

Comment: What about using `yarn` ? Can you try with this command "yarn dev" to run the web server for development.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal yarn is used in the demo project, but that has nothing to do with the problem, the behaviour would be the same with npm, that makes no difference

Answer (score -1):

With regard to the main issue, as far as I understand the issue, the use case and the desired behaviour.
The production build seems to work as expected, but the dev build + dev server
are breaking, IMO the easiest way to solve the issue is to condition value in the vite config based on build mode.
Here is the example I came up with:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import * as path from 'path'

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => ({
  plugins: [vue()],
  base: mode === 'production' ? '/vite-project/' : '/',
  build: {
    outDir: '../../../../target/classes/static/vite-project',
    assetsDir: '',
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        entryFileNames: `[name].js`,
        chunkFileNames: `[name].js`,
        assetFileNames: `[name].[ext]`
      }
    }
  },
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '.*': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8080',
        changeOrigin: true,
        ws: false,
        rewrite: (path) => path.startsWith('/t/') ? path : null
      }
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    }
  },
  define: {
    'process.env.MY_CUSTOM_BASE': '"t"',
  },
}))
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion (which is at least incomplete - e.g., what is the point of `MY_CUSTOM_BASE`, why `"t"`), but I could not get it to work. If you send me a pull request, I'll be happy to try it out again.

Comment: Here you go the related PR https://github.com/drahkrub/demo-spring-vite-vue3/pull/1

Assuming that the production build operates as expected, this Pull Request (PR) introduces a straightforward option to run the development server without the need for a custom base configuration. This extra base configuration is only added in the production environment.

Previously, I worked on a big PHP project that dynamically served Vue applications from varying routes. In this context, I found it challenging to fully comprehend the nuances of your production workflow. Could you provide more details?

Comment: Thanks for your PR! I checked it and in fact some problems in dev mode disappear (reload works, URL displayed in browser is ok). Unfortunately, the `/api` request on the about page does not reach the Spring Boot backend (the GET produces some example json, see the perfectly working vue-cli project). Instead `/api` is handled by the Vue Router which in return delivers the index.html. Which means that the proxying in the dev server is not working as expected. Unfortunately I'm starting into the weekend right now, so I'm a little bit in a hurry, can't write anymore. Cheers!